# Broadcast ARP request in C#

Tags: c#, arp

In Wireshark I found an ARP request which I would like to reproduce.

[image]

I have a basic understanding of ARP and I think that this is telling every device on the network to add 10.0.0.64 to the ARP table, if it is not already there. I would like to replicate this request in C#. With the exception that the "destination" should be a broadcast, rather than a specific device.

I currently have this code.

```
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Iphlpapi.dll", EntryPoint = "SendARP")]
        internal extern static Int32 SendArp(Int32 destIpAddress, Int32 srcIpAddress,
byte[] macAddress, ref Int32 macAddressLength);

        private static Int32 ConvertIPToInt32(IPAddress pIPAddr)
        {
            byte[] lByteAddress = pIPAddr.GetAddressBytes();
            return BitConverter.ToInt32(lByteAddress, 0);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            byte[] macAddr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("f4:6b:ef:6f:ae:09");

            int macAddrLen = macAddr.Length;

            SendArp(ConvertIPToInt32(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.71")), 0,
    macAddr, ref macAddrLen);

        }
```

But I don't fully understand it, or even know if it's what I'm looking for. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried setting the destination to 255.255.255.255 (broadcast)?

Comment: I've done that now, but how exactly does the SendArp function work? I see the parameters say "source IP" and the mac address, but what do those do? I've tried setting the destination to broadcast but in Wireshark I can't seem to find the request it was supposed to have made.

Comment: The mac address part seems incorrect: _Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("f4:6b:ef:6f:ae:09")_ will not return a 6 byte array with those byte values, instead it will return a 17 byte array containing the ascii values of each character in the string. You may instead want to do _new byte[] { 0xf4, 0x6b, 0xef, 0x6f, 0xae, 0x09 };_